# Class object deleting after post increment

Tags: c++, destructor, post-increment

I have a Weather class. So let's say I create an object of that class let's say `Weather object;` after that I have created pre and post increments to manipulate  the temperature of that weather. So when I do `++object;` the temperature increments by one perfectly, but when I do `object++;` the destructor is called, my pointer is deleted and my temperature then becomes random numbers. My question is, why in the world does the pre increment work, but after post incrementing the destructor is being called on that object? This is my WORKING pre increment:

```
Weather &Weather::operator++() {
    ++ptr->airTemperature;
    return *this;
}
```

And this is the NOT WORKING post increment:

```
Weather Weather::operator++(int) {
    Weather temp = *this;
    ++ptr->airTemperature;
    return temp;
}
```

As I understand pre increment returns itself and the post increment returns a copy, so I did that, but what could cause the issue?

Comment: You need to show the rest of your class, especially special members like constructors, destructors, and assignment operators. It seems that you didn't implement those properly. The destructor is perfectly allowed to be called, as technically you are copying `temp` to the return value, so then `temp` gets destroyed (although many compilers will elide that). So, your copy constructor needs to ensure it doesn't leave two objects referring to the same `ptr` or other members and double-deleting them or other wrong behaviours.

Comment: Did you implement copy-constructor, to copy the pointed-at value? The default copy constructor is just a bitwise copy - it copies over the pointer, but not what the pointer points at.

Comment: Oh thank you, I actually only had basic constructors, but not copy-constructors so I guess this is where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I would guess in your destructor for Weather you have ``delete ptr``. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: In modern c++ you should not be using delete unless you really need to.

Comment: Use std::shared_ptr to track a pointer that might be *owned* by multiple objects. Then you don't have to write custom copy constructors or destructors.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Thank you for the advice, I will try that.

Comment: I'll write you a quick example

Comment: That is, if it's OK for objects to refer to the _same_ `ptr`. If each need their own copy of pointed-to data and might need those to differ, then you'd want to implement deep copy, and can find info on that by searching SO. But at that point, you should consider why you use pointers at all: if it could just be a by-value member, you'll get deep copy (of it, not necessarily _its_ members) by default. So that's another option, assuming it's not too large or shared to be a by-value member. But yeah, generally, avoid points if you can (use values or references) and certain avoid `new` and `delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and you can avoid all copy constructors and destructors.

```
class Temp {
   double airTemperature;
};

class Weather {

    public:

    Weather(std::shared_ptr<Temp> tempPtr)
    : ptr(tempPtr){}

    std::shared_ptr<Temp> ptr;

    Weather Weather::operator++(int) {
        Weather temp = *this;
        ++ptr->airTemperature;
        return temp;
    }

    Weather &Weather::operator++() {
        ++ptr->airTemperature;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Of course consider if you really need a pointer to *Temp*. Perhaps you should be just doing this.

```
class Weather {

    public:

    Weather(Temp temp)
    : temp(temp){}

    Temp ptr;

    Weather Weather::operator++(int) {
        Weather temp = *this;
        ++temp.airTemperature;
        return temp;
    }

    Weather &Weather::operator++() {
        ++temp.airTemperature;
        return *this;
    }
};
```